# Adding event markers on table_calendar widget in flutter app not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add event markers in a table_calendar widget on the days that have events associated with the day. I am getting an error on the return statement in the _getEventsForDay() method.

Here is the code for _getEventsForDay():

```
  List<Events> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day, [List<Events>? events]) {
    final int today = day.day;
    return events[day] ?? [];  <<< ERROR HERE
  }
```

Here is the error I am getting on the events[day] ?? []; line:

```
A value of type 'Object' can't be returned from the method '_getEventsForDay' because it has a return type of 'List<Events>'.dartreturn_of_invalid_type
[List<Events>? events]
Type: List<Events>?
```

This is the Events model:

```
class Events {
  String? id;
  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;
```

I have tried the QuickFix suggestions but none of them work.

Here is the eventsLoader: where I call the method:

```
eventLoader: (day) {
        return events ?? _getEventsForDay(day, events);
      },
```

I am completely lost here. How do I fix this error?
Thanks

Comment: `_getEventsForDay` should return a list of event object. but in yout method, you just return `events[day]` which means only return an object og `event` and not a list.

Answer (score 0):

your method `List<Events> _getEventsForDay` is required to return a List, but you return an object `event`

in function parameter,
this `[List<event>?] events` this is not a nested list of event. its only a normal param that you put inside a list.

for example, I can put 2 or more param inside it.

```
 _getEventsForDay(DateTime day, [List<List<Events>?> events, String param2, int param3 ])
```

if you want to pass a nested list of event to your function, it should be like below

```
List<Events> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day, List<List<Events>?> events){
  // since events is a nested list, to get the value you have to use index
  return events[1]; 
}
```

---

in the documentation, the example are using `Map<DateTime, List<Event>>`
so this is a better way, you can get the event by the `DateTime`